# Django cant read variables

Tags: python, django, model, processors

I have a problem with django
In my views.py i have this

```
def home(request):
    template = "index.html"
    test = "hello"
    Settings = settings.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(template ,{"Settings" : settings}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And in my index.html

```
{{test}}
```

But it doesnt return anything
Also my model has a field called logo_img if i write

```
{{ Settings.logo_img }}
```

Doesnt work either , any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the test variable with "hello":

```
def home(request):
    template = "index.html"
    test = "hello"
    return render_to_response(template, {"test": test})
```

As long as your templates directory is configured correctly, and index.html is found, this should work.
I'm not sure what you are using the variable "Settings" for. It's not being referenced after you assign it.

Comment: It worked :D thz , i have another question , is there a way to return the setting model but without using {% for %} ?